# Buscar caracter en índice del arreglo

Tags: vb.net

Tengo un código en el cual se ingresan letras y números en un arreglo.

Tengo 2 funciones:

1. Para verificar que las letras que se ingresen no sean vocales.
2. Para verificar que el número ingresado sea par.

Para buscar la vocal tengo problemas, no me funciona con 2 vocales y con el resto si. Si escribo algunas consonantes también me genera error.

```
Sub Main()

        Dim arreglo(6) As Char

        CrearArreglo(arreglo)

    End Sub

    Function CrearArreglo(ByRef arreglo() As Char) As Char()

        Console.WriteLine("Ingresar 3 letras que no sean VOCALES")

        For i As UShort = 0 To 2 Step 1
            arreglo(i) = Console.ReadLine()
            ValidarLetraVocal(arreglo, i)
            Console.ReadLine()
        Next
        Console.WriteLine("Ingresar 4 numeros que sean PARES")
        For x As UShort = 2 To 5 Step 1
            arreglo(x) = Console.ReadLine()
            ValidarNumeroPar(arreglo, x)
        Next
        Return arreglo
    End Function

    Function ValidarLetraVocal(ByRef arreglo() As Char, ByRef i As UShort) As Boolean



        For i = 0 To arreglo.Length - 1
            Select Case arreglo(i)
                Case "A", "a", "E", "e", "I", "i", "O", "o", "U", "u"
                    Console.WriteLine("ERROR, ES UNA VOCAL!")
                    Return False
            End Select
        Next
        Return True

    End Function

    Function ValidarNumeroPar(ByRef arreglo() As Char, ByRef x As UShort) As Boolean

        Dim buscarValor As String
        Dim aux As UShort

        aux = Convert.ToUInt16(arreglo(x))

        For Each buscarValor In arreglo
            ''Microsoft.VisualBasic.AscW
            If aux Mod 2 = 0 Then
                Return True
            End If

        Next
        Console.WriteLine("ERROR, ES IMPAR!")
        Return False
    End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si declaras el array con una longitud de 6 (`Dim arreglo(6) As Char`), no puedes ponerle 7 elementos (3 letras + 4 números), por lo que debería ser:

```
Dim arreglo(7) As Char
```

Luego cometes un error en la función `CrearArreglo`, en la captura de los números, pues estás sobre escribiendo la posición 2 del arreglo, debería ser entre la posición 3 y la 6:

```
    Console.WriteLine("Ingresar 4 números que sean PARES")
    For x As UShort = 3 To 6 Step 1
        arreglo(x) = Console.ReadLine()
        ValidarNumeroPar(arreglo, x)
    Next
    Return arreglo
```